# Alternative approaches to Zudilin's proof of Apéry's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function

The article

> Wadim Zudilin, *Apéry's theorem. Thirty years after*, Int. J. Math. Comput. Sci. 4 (2009), no. 1 pp 9–19. (arXiv:[math/0202159](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202159), with the title *An elementary proof of Apéry's theorem*)

introduces the functions $R_n(t)=\displaystyle {\Big{(}} \frac{(t-1)..(t-n)}{t(t+1)..(t+n)} {\Big{)}}^2$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $t \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z_-$.

Zudilin proves that $A_n=B_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, where
$$
A_n=\sum_{t=1}^{+ \infty} R'_n(t)
$$
and
$$
B_n=\sum_{t=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{(n!)^2 (2t+n)(t-1) \dots (t-n)(t+n+1) \dots (t+2n)}{(t(t+1) \dots (t+n))^4} \ .
$$

To prove this he shows that $A_n$ and $B_n$ satisfy both a same explicit recurrence relation of order $2$ with same initial condition. Did anyone have an idea to prove that $A_n=B_n$ using any other method, for instance, integral representation of $A_n$, hypergeometric sum etc.?